# How to print out found words from a trie in java?

Tags: java, search, trie

I have a method here that searches and prints what i think is all letter combinations of a dictionary in trie form the node entered. 
I want to specify each print out and and it to my search(string x) method that finds if a word is in the dictionary. 
I can't work out how to specify each letter combination as a string. I am printing them out on a line but don't know how to make that line of print a string to pass into the search method.

```
public void print(Node node) { 

    if(node == null) return;  
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++) {  
        if(node.next[i] != null) {
            //printing each character  
            System.out.print((char) (97 + i)); 

            //identifying letter combo                
            if(node.next[i].isWord == true) { 

                 //here i want to make that combo a string                  
                 System.out.println();
            }  
            print(node.next[i]);  
        }  

    }  
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is a little bit odd.

Comment: I didnt fully understand your requirement. But maybe this can be helpful.

`String s1; s1 = s1 + (char)(97+i);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
           `String s1 = "";
            s1 = s1 + (char)(97+i);` to append characters to a string. You can pass this to your `search` function

Something, this way,

Initialise the string to `""` outside the for loop `String s1 = ""`

While looping keep adding the characters to the `String` to maintain a string

```
    s1 = s1 + (char)(97+i);
```

Now,

```
if(node.next[i].isWord == true) 
{ 
  //u can use the String here;  
             System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Comment: why did you add 'i' with 97? what is 97?